# Excel AverageIf Formula Doesn't Follow Condition

Tags: excel-formula

Consider the following spreadsheet:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sheldon | Leonard | Penny | Raj | Howard |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | A+ | C | B+ | A- | A | Raj | 14.7 | 11.25 | 13.2 | 13.8 | 14.25 |
| 3 | A+ | C | A+ | A- | A+ | Penny | 14.7 | 11.25 | 14.7 | 13.8 | 14.7 |
| 4 | A | A | A | A | A | Leonard | 14.25 | 14.25 | 14.25 | 14.25 | 14.25 |
| 5 | A+ | B+ | A+ | A+ | A+ | Howard | 14.7 | 13.2 | 14.7 | 14.7 | 14.7 |
| 6 | A | B+ | A- | B+ | A- | Sheldon | 14.25 | 13.2 | 13.8 | 13.2 | 13.8 |

The data are from students grading other students. Columns A to E reflect the letter grades given, and columns G to K represent these grades converted into numbers. A1:E1 are the names of the students graded, and Column F is the names of the people doing the grading.

I want to get an average of each student's grades, omitting the grade they gave themselves.

I tried

```
=AVERAGEIF($F$2:$F$6, "<>A1", G$2:G$6)
```

to average the grades for Sheldon, but it isn't working. It should be leaving out the grade that Sheldon gave himself (A = 14.25). But that mean is 14.58. 14.52 is the mean for all 5 values. What is going wrong?

Comment: If you post your data as text (using [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) (read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16578424) for an explanation)) it is much easier to help you.

Answer (score 1):

It works OK here on Excel (Office 16). Quick test data

| Student | A | B | C | D | Average | AverageIf |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 2.5 | 3 |
| B | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 3.5 | 3.666666667 |
| C | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 6.5 | 6.333333333 |
| D | 56 | 7 | 8 | 1111 | 295.5 | 23.66666667 |

Where the average if is defined to exclude the numbers along the diagonal with the following syntax:

```
=AVERAGEIF(B$1:E$1,"<>"&A2,B2:E2)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Martin Brown's answer didn't do exactly what I was trying to do, but gave me the solution... I had "<>A1" for my condition. Using "<>"&A1 works

```
=AVERAGEIF($F$2:$F$6, "<>"&A1, G$2:G$6)
```